# Sending JSON over AJAX to PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, bigcommerce

I am attempting to create a method to take a CSV file, parse it into JSON, then send it to BigCommerce using their REST API. Initially I was going to use Javascript to do the whole thing, and everything up until actually connected to BigCommerce to PUT the data worked. BigCommerce doesn't allow CORS, resulting in a 401 response from the server and none of my data actually being sent. Because of this, I was going to switch to do it with PHP but being able to get the specific JSON object is much harder than it was with Javascript. The solution I've come up with would be for me to parse the data in Javascript, send it line by line to the PHP script and the PHP script would then connect to BigCommerce and send it for me.

First off, is this possible?

Here is some of my Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('[type=file]').change(function () {
                if (!("files" in this)) {
                    alert("File reading not supported in this browser");
                }
                var file = this.files && this.files[0];
                if (!file) {
                    return;
                }


                i=0;
                Papa.parse(file, {
                    delimiter: ",", // auto-detect
                    newline: "",    // auto-detect
                    header: true,
                    dynamicTyping: true,
                    preview: 0,
                    encoding: "",
                    worker: false,
                    comments: false,
                    step: function(results, parser) {
                        console.log("Row data:", results.data);
                        console.log("Row errors:", results.errors);
                        currentID = results.data[i]["id"];
                        currentResult = results.data[i];
                        sendToBC(currentID, currentResult);
                        i+1;
                    },
                    complete: function(results, file) {
                        console.log("Parsing complete:", results, file);
                        $("#parsed_JSON").css("display", "block");
                        $("#ready_btn").css("display", "block");
                        $("#select_file").css("display", "none");
                        $("#retry_btn").css("display", "block");
                    },
                    error: function(error, file) {
                        console.log("Parsing failed:", error, file);
                        alert("Parsing failed. Check file and refresh to try again.");
                    },
                    download: false,
                    skipEmptyLines: true,
                    chunk: undefined,
                    fastMode: undefined,
                    beforeFirstChunk: undefined,
                    withCredentials: undefined

                })
            });

            function sendToBC(id,data) {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "PUT",
                    url: "https://store.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products/" + id + "/discountrules.json",
                    data: data,
                    xhrFields: {
                        withCredentials: true
                    },
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('username:key')
                    },
                    dataType:"json",
                    async: false,

                    success: function() {
                        alert("success")
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                      console.log(error);
                    }

                });
            }
```

You'll notice I had to do something weird with the i=0 and the i+1 in the middle of the papa code but that was because I couldn't do a for loop in the step function.

My php is just the basic curl functions:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ('Accept: application/json', 'Content-Length: 0') );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:key" );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $complete);  
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    $response = curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close ($ch)
```

I dont have the most experience with PHP especially with passing values into it through AJAX, so any help would be great. I'm not really certain how passing values between the files really works and how I can send this data to the PHP the best way programatically.

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of reading the csv file in javascript, why don't you upload it to PHP. and then let php read, parse and call the API via CURL?

Comment: The PHP function json_encode encodes the data correctly, but i cant access a single JSON object to send it to the BigCommerce API, which is important because the ID for each item will be changing.

Comment: `json_encode` will turn an array to a `JSON` string. If your `json` string is not turning to a `json` object as `{}`. Then pass `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` as 2nd param to `json_encode`. May be, this is what you are looking for?

Comment: I can't seem to get just a single JSON object. Each object looks like "{"id": "77", "min": "1", "max": "6", "price": 10} and I need to be able to grab one at a time and pull the id then send the object/string to the API.

Comment: If each of the rows from `csv` are separate `json` object. you can combine them to an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so the way I ended up doing it was just using PHP and building a JSON string on my own with the values retrieved from the array by their key. So I did:

```
contents[$i]['id']
```

to get the id of the current item and stored it in a variable and did that for all the other columns of the csv. Then I built a string like this:

```
$jsonObject[] = '{"min": '.$min.',"max": '.$max.',"type": "'.$type.'","type_value": '.$value.'}';
```

and sent it through the API to Bigcommerce using CURL.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you get an string object like `{"id": "77", "min": "1", "max": "6", "price": 10}`. and you want to retrieve id (`77`) from the `JSON` object.

```
$str = '{"id": "77", "min": "1", "max": "6", "price": 10}';
$jsonObj = json_decode($str);
$jsonObj->id; // the id.
```

Here `$jsonObj->id` is the id via which you can call your API.

Comment: Yeah that's basically what I ended up doing and just built the JSON string on my own to send along to the API. Thanks for the help man, you put me on the right path.